# How to change marker's color in maps?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I need some help to change a marker color, in android using android studio.

I put all the markers in the map. Perfect.

I would like to show a message when the user select the point. To get sure, the user must click twice in the marker.

Everything ok, the user does this, I change the color and the marker changes.

BUT, when I click in another mark or whathever place in the map, the color returns the original.

It seems that I change the wrong mark (another object).

This is the method to print the markers

```
public void plot(){
        NumberFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0");
        for (Coordinate c: pointsList) {
            LatLng temp = new LatLng(c.getLat(), c.getLng());
            Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(temp)
                    .title("Ponto " + c.getDescricao())
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
            marker.setTag("Ponto " + c.getDescricao());
        }
    }
```

I have a listener to him and its show a message wit 2 options, confirm or cancel:

```
@Override
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        getSelectedPoint().setSnippet("Selected!");
                getSelectedPoint().setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));

    }
```

and

> ```
> @Override
> public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
>     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cancel the dialog", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
> }
> ```

Somebody can help-me? I Need that color stays AZURE, not returns to RED.

EDIT1: When I click in the marker again, the color is correct, AZURE. But, when click in another place, the color returns to RED.

EDIT2: The code

```
public class Navigator extends FragmentActivity
        implements FragmentoDialogo.NoticeDialogListener, OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {      

    private static Marker pontoSelecionado;    

    public Marker getPontoSelecionado() {
        return pontoSelecionado;
    }

    public void setPontoSelecionado(Marker pontoSelecionado) {
        this.pontoSelecionado = pontoSelecionado;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */,
                        this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        pointsList = b.getParcelableArrayList("Points");

        setContentView(R.layout.navigator_ac);

        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        plotarPontosDeColeta();
        plotarCaminhamento();

        escutarCliqueMarcador();
        // Turn on the My Location layer and the related control on the map.
        updateLocationUI();

        // Get the current location of the device and set the position of the map.
        getDeviceLocation();

        LatLng ponto1 = new LatLng(pointsList.get(1).getLat(), pointsList.get(1).getLng());

        CameraPosition cameraPos = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(ponto1)
                .zoom(45).bearing(20).tilt(80).build();

        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPos), null);
    }

    public void plotarPontosDeColeta(){
        NumberFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0");
        for (Coordinate c: pointsList) {
            LatLng temp = new LatLng(c.getLat(), c.getLng());
            Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(temp)
                    .title("Ponto " + c.getDescricao())
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
            marker.setTag("Ponto " + c.getDescricao());
        }
    }

    private void plotarCaminhamento() {
        NumberFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0");

        ArrayList<Polyline> listaLinhas = new ArrayList<>();
        final ArrayList<MarkerOptions> listaMarcadores = new ArrayList<>();
        PolylineOptions lineOptions;

        try {
            for (int i=0; i<pointsList.size(); i++){
                LatLng aux1 = new LatLng(pointsList.get(i).getLat(),pointsList.get(i).getLng());
                LatLng aux2 = new LatLng(pointsList.get(i+1).getLat(),pointsList.get(i+1).getLng());
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions().clickable(true).add(aux1).add(aux2);
                Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
                polyline.setTag(i);
                listaLinhas.add(polyline);

                listaMarcadores.add(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(PointsHandler.encontrarPontoMedio(aux1, aux2))
                        .alpha(0f)
                        .title(""+ format.format(pointsList.get(i).getDistanciaProximoPonto()) + "m"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            //TODO
        }

        mMap.setOnPolylineClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onPolylineClick(Polyline polyline)
            {
                int tag = (Integer) polyline.getTag();
                mMap.addMarker(listaMarcadores.get(tag)).showInfoWindow();
            }
        });
    }

    public void escutarCliqueMarcador(){
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                if (getPontoSelecionado() == null) {
                    setPontoSelecionado(marker);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Clique novamente para confirmar!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }

                if (getPontoSelecionado().getTag().equals(marker.getTag())) {
                    showDialog();
                } else {
                    setPontoSelecionado(marker);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Clique novamente para confirmar!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void showDialog() {
        DialogFragment dialog = new FragmentoDialogo();
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "FragmentoDialogo");
    }
    @Override
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        getPontoSelecionado().setSnippet("Coleta efetuada");
        getPontoSelecionado().setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
        getPontoSelecionado().showInfoWindow();            
    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Ponto não confirmado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems you call `plot()` again after marker color change. And marker recreated with `RED` color.

Comment: It looks like, but I have no call.
I call the `plot()` once, in `onMapReady()`

Comment: Please share you source code with `plot()` call.

Comment: Tnks @AndriiOmelchenko. I've updated my question and put the most important methods..

Comment: This the original code, the `plot()` method, in really is `plotarPontosDeColeta()` .. Brazilian code...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself.

I created a `Coordinate` vector as a class attribute, started in the constructor and in the `plot()` method I add to that vector. For some reason, I was working with different instances.